# Odoo function not working

Tags: python, odoo

OpenErp 8 - Python

I have field. When use change `compute_date` then click button Save. Change state_for_date  :

if `compute_date` > 20 then state_for_date = comp

if `compute_date` < 20 then state_for_date = new

`state_for_date`  is `statusbar`

```
compute_date = fields.Integer('Int')

state_for_date = fields.Selection([('new', 'New'),
                                       ('comp', 'Comp')],
                                        'State', default='new', required=True)

 def write(self, vals):

       if self.compute_date < 20:
             vals = {'state': 'new'}

       if self.compute_date > 20:
             vals = {'state': 'comp'}

       return self.write(vals)
```

**Not working**, **help me**
*Error : RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded*

Comment: Your recursion needs some condition to stop recursing. Also your function makes no sense. It takes this argument `vals` which it doesn't read, only replaces and stuffs back into itself. Did you realise that this function is actually calling itself?

Comment: So. How to return state for 'compute_date'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling recursive write method instead of calling super method. 
You need to call super method.

```
def write(self, vals):
    if self.compute_date < 20:
        vals = {'state': 'new'}
    if self.compute_date > 20:
        vals = {'state': 'comp'}
    return super(class_name, self).write(vals)
```